# regexp accepts either all numbers or all letters

Tags: regex

I need a regexp works like this: it only accepts strings made up of all numbers or all letters (for example: "111111111111","aaaaaaaa", not "aaaaa11111").

I tried this
 `/(^[0-9]+$) | (^[a-z]$)/.test('111111111111')`, not working though.
What's the right way to do it ?

Comment: There's no need for the parentheses in each alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the spaces, and second, your `[a-z]` is lacking a `+`. So, the working version is:

```
/(^[0-9]+$)|(^[a-z]+$)/
```